# How to display a selection option Adaptive Card in PVA Teams using Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, power-virtual-agents

I am new to PVA and everything associated with it. I currently have a working multiple choice Herocard for Teams that displays a menu option for the user, whatever option they choose the PVA topic is redirected. In test bot PVA it shows a nice vertical selection, but when I publish and channel with Teams, it looks like this image,
[Teams Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8KXK.png)

So, I figured maybe I can create a Adaptive Card that can have the same functionality, but with the vertical selection option for Teams like this image,
[Adaptive Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dgw6.png)

I'm not very familiar with Adaptive Cards, though I have tried a few iterations using Containers and TextBlocks. It was able to be displayed in the Test bot as well as teams, but I wasn't able to click on an option and be redirected to a different topic. I've come to the conclusion that ActionSets may be the key to allowing the user to click on a selection box and redirect to another PVA topic (Correct me if I'm wrong please :D, or maybe I missed something when trying the Containers and Textblocks)

Does anyone have an idea on how I can bridge this adaptive card to Bot Framework Composer to display the adaptive card in teams for users to select an option and that option would then redirect to another PVA topic. I know I'm missing something to be able to communicate with my Adaptive Card on Bot Framework Composer, heres an image
[Bot Framework Composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRogE.png)

AdaptiveCard
`

````
[import](common.lg)
# adaptivecardjson_Main_Menu(Location)
- ```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.5",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Employee Handbook",
                    "associatedInputs": "none"
                }
            ],
            "spacing": "Small",
            "separator": true,
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "id": "dialog.UserChoice"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "spacing": "Small",
            "separator": true,
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Policy Manual",
                    "associatedInputs": "none"
                }
            ],
            "id": "dialog.UserChoice"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "spacing": "Small",
            "separator": true,
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Payroll",
                    "associatedInputs": "none"
                }
            ],
            "id": "dialog.UserChoice"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "spacing": "Small",
            "separator": true,
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Insurance Benefits",
                    "associatedInputs": "none"
                }
            ],
            "id": "dialog.UserChoice"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "spacing": "Small",
            "separator": true,
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Health Savings Account",
                    "associatedInputs": "none"
                }
            ],
            "id": "dialog.UserChoice"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "spacing": "Small",
            "separator": true,
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "401(k)",
                    "associatedInputs": "none"
                }
            ],
            "id": "dialog.UserChoice"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "spacing": "Small",
            "separator": true,
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Other",
                    "associatedInputs": "none"
                }
            ],
            "id": "dialog.UserChoice"
        }
    ]
}```

# AdaptiveCard_Main_Menu(Location)
[Activity
    Attachments = ${json(adaptivecardjson_Main_Menu(Location))}
]


# SendActivity_XJFtJ8()
- ${AdaptiveCard_Main_Menu(virtualagent.user_city)}
````

I listed what I tried above, I really need someone else's insights, ideas or maybe someone knows a solution to this. I was expecting to somehow connect a condition called dialog.UserChoice that would allow for the Adaptive Card to display the options and with Bot Framework with whatever option that is selected to be redirected to that topic.

Comment: We are not able to repro the scenario. It is working fine from our end.
Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.32970 (64-bit)
Could please remove the dialog.UserChoice condition and check it once?
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnJWp.png

Comment: If I were to remove the dialog.UserChoice, I won’t be able to redirect the conversation to another topic I have on PVA. I need it to display vertically as well as when a user clicks on one of the 7 options, the options redirected to the appropriate topic. Any thoughts of that? @Sayali-MSFT

Comment: Please have look into this sample-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-bot-framework-composer-example2
hope it's helpful.